# How to keep an SVG line the same height as a parent div, where the height is not specified?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

So I'm trying to place an SVG line in between two columns, but the line isn't taking the height of the parent container. The parent container doesn't have a height specified since I want it to automatically scale to the highest column.

**Example:**  https://jsfiddle.net/Lye0z5wx/4/

**Code**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
      <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo
        quis fringilla.</p>
    </div>
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <line x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(235,235,235);stroke-width:1" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
      <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo
        quis fringilla.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've been trying several things to make this work but the SVG line keeps scaling down when resizing the browser. When I want it to contain the full height of the parent div.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could set a border-right:1px solid stroke:rgb(235,235,235) on the first column, so you wouldn't even need an svg there.

Comment: Not sure if I could center it perfectly that way, how would you do that?

Comment: Centered line using border and padding: [https://jsfiddle.net/y53d0wL6/](https://jsfiddle.net/y53d0wL6/)

Comment: That is a lot more simple indeed! Also better browser compatibility so I'll use this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` from `svg` element and add `align-self` property as *stretch* so that the *flexbox* itself will stretch it out over the full height of the *flexbox* - see demo below and [**`updated fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/uj45k13b/):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;

}

.column h3{
  color: #1c3653;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column p {
  color: #1c3653;
  font-size: 15px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 20%;
  align-self: stretch; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
    <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis
      fringilla.</p>
  </div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <line x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(235,235,235);stroke-width:1" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  <div class="column">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
    <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis
      fringilla.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the padding hack:

You wrap your svg on a container `.svgDiv` in this case.
The `.svgDiv` has `height:0` and `padding-top:100%` making it as height as the container. Then you gan give your svg the width and the height of the container.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline:1px solid;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;

}

.column h3{
  color: #1c3653;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column p {
  color: #1c3653;
  font-size: 15px;
}

svg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.svgDiv{ 
   width: 10%;
   height:0;
   padding-top:100%;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
   <h3>Content</h3>
   <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
   <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis fringilla.</p>
  </div>
    
    <div class="svgDiv">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 
      <line x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
    </svg>
    </div>
    
  <div class="column">
   <h3>Content</h3>
   <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
   <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis fringilla.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Yet another way of doing it would be

- You wrap your svg on a container `.svgDiv` in this case
- you change `align-items: center;`to  `align-items: stretch;` for the container
- To keep the text in the center you add `align-self:center;` for the columns.
- next you give your SVG the width and the height of the `.svgDiv` (100%)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  outline:1px solid;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  align-self:center;
}

.column h3{
  color: #1c3653;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column p {
  color: #1c3653;
  font-size: 15px;
}

svg {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}

.svgDiv{ 
width: 10%;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
   <h3>Content</h3>
   <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
   <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis fringilla.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="svgDiv">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 
      <line x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
    </svg>
     </div>
  <div class="column">
   <h3>Content</h3>
   <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
   <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis fringilla.</p>
      <p>Easily change/switch/swap every placeholder inside every image on Sedna with the included Sketch files. You’ll have this template customised to suit your business in no time!</p>
   <p>Nam vehicula malesuada lectus, interdum fringilla nibh. Duis aliquam vitae metus a pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum augue quis augue ornare, eget faucibus felis pharetra. Proin condimentum et leo quis fringilla.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to add a height to `.container` and the `.column` [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bxc0j8gp/)

```
div.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 350px;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
```